# Curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

Tags: curl, solr, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

On my RHEL server, I have created keyspace `keyspace1` and table `table1` in Cassandra and also configured SOLR successfully. Now I want to create a SOLR core so I write:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=keyspace1.table1&generateResources=true"
```

But I am getting the error

```
Curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Help appreciated !!

Comment: Your curl command looks correct. Please verify that Cassandra&Solr are both up and running. If you are using DSE Search, verify that the node was started correctly in the search mode (see http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchInstall.html) for further details.

Comment: yes I am able to do other operations like create table on cassandra as well as opened the SOLR link, which works perfectly.

Comment: Can you make your system log available? Also make sure that really something is running on port **8983** using e.g. `netstat -nat |grep 8983`

Comment: I would recommend you using dsetool insetad to create the core. Still if you can 'open the solr link' try pasting the url in that same browser and it should work.

Comment: It works in the browser when I pasted the link, but on browser I put the server ip instead of localhost. On my other machine, it works with localhost

Comment: Did you run the command directly  from the Cassandra node?

Comment: Did you check your IP tables on your Solr host? (try "iptables --list"). See if port 8983 is accepted.

Comment: Go to whatever browser you had solr UI on 8983 responding, paste the link you were feeding to curl, adjust to ip or localhost accordingly and it should work.

Comment: @phact yes I ran the link on my cassandra node and it gives me the above mentioned error

Comment: Agree with Bereng, if it works from the browser with an IP use an IP from curl and it will work as well.

Comment: @Yann I tried iptables --list, its showing me target prot opt source destination for chain input,forward and output

Comment: (phact, bereng) I agree it works with IP, but on my earlier node it was working with localhost, I need to make it work on localhost so that I don't have to write IP on every script I want to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it by adding the below line to /etc/hosts

```
`server private ip` localhost localhost.localdomain
```